# i need to add image without intent to email

Tags: android, image, android-intent, jakarta-mail, inline

there is a send button on clicking which the contents goes implicitly to mail, the recipient email will be entered by the user. i have added address, subject, content but image has to be loaded from the first activity not from internal storage of pc. using mimebodypart and file datasource i cannot add imageuri in filedata source, i have to import the image captured in MAINACTIVITY and send it through email without intent

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA:

```
    String email=et_email.getText().toString();
    String subject=et_subject.getText().toString();
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message,imageUri);
    sm.execute();
```

SENDMAIL.JAVA:

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
         {
         //Declaring Variables
            private Context context;
            private Session session;

              //Information to send email
            private String email;
           private String subject;
           private String msg;
         ImageView imageView;
           Uri imageUri;
        //Progressdialog to show while sending email
     private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

     //Class Constructor
     public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String msg, Uri imageUri) {
        //Initializing variables
        this.context = context;
        this.email = email;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.msg = msg;
        this.imageUri=imageUri;
      }

        @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog while sending email
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
              }

          @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        //Dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //Showing a success message
        Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Creating properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        //Configuring properties for gmail
        //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        //Creating a new session
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    //Authenticating the password
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                    }
                });

          try {
            //Creating MimeMessage object
            MimeMessage message= new MimeMessage(session);

            //Setting sender address
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
            //Adding receiver
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            //Adding subject
            message.setSubject(subject);
            //Adding message
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = msg+imageUri;
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, \"Title\", null)");

            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

            // add image to the multipart
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It isn't clear from your question what the problem is. What isn't working as expected?

Comment: i want to send the captured image in email without intent, as u can see from the code i need to pass the captured image as an argument to sendMail.java so that it can come in my email

Comment: OK. So what is the problem? What isn't working as you expect it to?

Comment: the image isnt coming while sending email

Comment: Well, you should try adding a small well-known file as an attachment first and see if that works. Analyze the problem step by step.